# installed anaconda and when I run pandas it won't work. Is there a fix to this? Do I need to uninstall and reinstall for this to work?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

---

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-7dd3504c366f> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
      9 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     10     try:
---> 11         __import__(dependency)
     12     except ImportError as e:
     13         missing_dependencies.append(f"{dependency}: {e}")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    136 
    137     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 138     from . import _distributor_init
    139 
    140     from . import core

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     28         if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, 
winmode)
    379 
    380         if handle is None:
--> 381             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    382         else:
    383             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I tried to "import pandas as pd" and this is the output in the jupyter notebook. what does the traceback(most recent call last) mean? Also why are there arrows pointing at specific lines?

Comment: Does your anaconda environment include pandas?

Comment: yes, when I open anaconda3 and search for pandas it comes up. Would you recommend uninstalling and reinstalling or would this not work?